# A script wrapper that turns SIGINT into SIGHUP

Tags: linux, shell, signals

I use Leiningen REPL that uses SIGINT to interrupt currently running code and to output a new prompt. The REPL can be stopped using SIGHUP or SIGKILL. I don't actually run anything in the REPL - I just use it for some pre-defined side-effects.

The problem is that IntelliJ IDEA can only send SIGINT when it exits to the processes that it has started. So if I forget to kill a REPL started from IDEA, there'll be a dandling process that I have to kill manually.

Is it possible to write a shell script that starts the REPL, gives it some dummy stdin/stdout (otherwise, REPL immediately quits), and waits for the process to end, while also forwarding it all signals, transforming SIGINT into SIGHUP or SIGKILL?

Comment: If you want a sig forwarder/forwarder-translator, I recommend writing it in C. I've tried doing this in the shell, but ran into issues. For this kind of thing it's better to have the kind of control that C gives you.

Comment: @PSkocik yeah, that's the solution I've been thinking about, only in Python. I will do exactly that once I clearly understand that there're no other options or that they're not worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Python code does what's needed:

```
from subprocess import call
import sys

try:
    call(sys.argv[1:])
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

All its parameters are the command line that you want to be executed. The running application will always be closed by `SIGINT`.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window and start the REPL inside of it. The process will terminate when you close the terminal window or when you press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> on Windows).

You can then minify the terminal window, so it doesn't annoy.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question since it's not a run configuration, and consequently doesn't have its advantages like storing multiple parameters without a hassle, having stuff automatically run before the configuration, having compound configurations.

Comment: I see. This is a bit weird, though. I'm not sure how IDEA starts the process. If it uses the Java API, then the stdin of the REPL process is connected to the IDEA console. When IDEA terminates, the REPL process will read EOF from stdin and then it should terminate automatically. Maybe it's a bug of the TTY emulation used by the IDE's console view?

Comment: There's a bash process in between IDEA and REPL since IDEA doesn't let you run arbitrary programs. But this script contains only hashbang and `lein $@`. I agree, it's weird that the bash process is not terminated. Maybe they don't terminate processes on purpose when you hit "Cancel" in the "Waiting for process detach" dialog.

Comment: Does it pass any options to bash? What is the parent PID of the bash process?

Comment: IDEA passes only options that I ask it to pass. I don't have the access to the process' PID from IDEA.